# Assembly resource missing exception with MonoTouch

Tags: c#, resources, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, resx

I'm facing an assembly resource missing exception with MonoTouch. I don't know what to do.

The context: I've ported some existing code from SL to WP7 and MonoTouch. Internationalization is performed via satellite assemblies. Resources XYZ.Designer.cs is generated using the ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx.

So under MonoTouch: I've the XYZ.de.resx, XYZ.fr.resx, etc... The compilation from MonoDevelop gives me the de/XYZ.resources.dll, fr/XYZ.resources.dll, etc...

On the simulator, I get a System.Resources.MissingManifetResourcesException!

A quick check on the app package shows me that the satellite assemblies de/XYZ.resources.dll, fr/XYZ.resources.dll are really missing.

Cheers, patrick

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake, a typo on the definition of the default namespace.
Once the default namespace is ok, everything works as expected. Sorry guys.